JAR package only necessary classes and dependencies
I am new to maven and I would like to know what would be the best way to package only those classes and dependencies that are needed to run that class. For example if I have a lot of classes A, B, C in my project structure but I would like to only package one of those classes, A in my jar (plus dependencies and classes it needs) how can I do that? I have tried using the shaded plugin but I keep running into issues.
Any advice is appreciated
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>com/A.class</include>
                                        <include>com/B.class</include>
                                        <include>org/apache/commons/**</include>
                                        <!-- include all other dependencies -->
                                    </includes>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


So you want to create an executable jar... yes a way is to use maven-shade-plugin but I strongly recommend to use more up-to-date version of that plugin (the given version in ancient old)...check https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ also to get an executable jar you have to define a main class in the shade configuration...The createDependencyReducedPom is not required...

I do not know of any existing way to do that. The maven shade plugin lets you minimize dependencies, but not eliminate classes of your own project.
